# Device tilting up/down and sideways triggers orientation notification

Tags: ios, autorotate

I have an application build for iOS7 with a UIViewController that should support landscape left-right and portrait - portrait upside down and other ViewControllers should support landscape left and right orientation alone. I have used the notification to notify the orientation change and refresh the subviews accordingly. I am also checking UIDevice's current orientation to rotate. The **issue I am facing is that, even a slight shake or tilt triggers orientation change method** which refreshes the views. I even get bizarre view frames then and there. I use **beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications** and **endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications** on viewDidLoad and viewWillDisappear respectively. Is there any way I can restrict to device rotation alone?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceDidRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]; // adding observer to notify when device rotates.
```

deviceDidRotate: gets called even for a small tilt or shake which I actually want to avoid.

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
        //Ignoring specific orientations
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp||orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown     ||orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown)
 {
    return;
 }
if ((UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))) {
            [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}
```

To avoid the tilt effect I am using this delegate method

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self handleViewArrangementWithCurrentOrientation];
}
```

How can I skip notification trigger on slight shake or tilt. I am actually having a animation on view refresh on orientation change which gives a flickering kind of effect and its frequent. I need to remove this. Please help guys.

Comment: Tilting up/down is rotation around the X-axis, not Z-axis.

Comment: Yes, UIDevice orientation fluctuates rapidly. You shouldn't use it to set your view controller rotations. Is there a reason you can't use viewDidRotate in your view controller(s)? Or, better yet, use autolayout?

Comment: @AnnaDickinson: I am using auto layout. Its not the issue with layout. I get my code for view refresh being called even for a small shake/tilt due to notification being triggered on it. What can I do to avoid this. Users would feel this as a bug. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why are you using notifications for view refresh?

Comment: @AnnaDickinson: Then what to use to trigger rotation change. I read from apple docs to use notifications for the same and use the required enums and filter out the others which I am doing. I don't understand what is going wrong here. Please help me as I am stuck on this for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a more complete answer than my comment)

When handling view controller rotations, you can't use the *device* rotation from [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation -- that gives you the instantaneous orientation of the device.  It doesn't necessarily match the *interface* orientation, and can change back and forth rapidly.

The *interface* orientation is handled by the responder chain.  UIViewControllers receive messages when it changes.  These messages happen when the orientation has stabilized, and will not fluctuate rapidly.

To handle rotation:

- First, in iOS 8 docs, look at "Handling View Rotations" in
  [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)
- Pre-iOS8, override
  [didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:)
  in your ViewController. Your view controller receives this
  when the device rotates.  You handle the rotation at that time.
- Starting in iOS8, use the [Transition
  Coordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013295)
  mechanism.  Set your transition coordinator using the transitionCoordinator property of the view controller.

Or, you can avoid handling rotations altogether if you've set up your autolayout constraints completely.  See (http://annabd351.github.io/SquareCropViewController) for a good example of a view controller which handles some tricky rotation scenarios with almost no code.

Comment: Thanks Anna. I found your answer useful.